# i want to have a dropdown of firebase document but can`t get the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have edited and works fine, but i want to add that list of **email_id** in the dropdown but doesn`t works

i know it has to be stored in the array but cant get idea hot it works

```
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      emailcatch()
        .then((emails) => {
          setItems(emails.map((email) => ({ label: email, value: email })));
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    } catch {
      console.log("error in main")
    }
  }, []);


  var email_user=[];
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(email_user);
```

```
  const getUserEmails =() =>{



try {
      const emailcatch = dob.collection("users")
      .where('email_id', '!=', "")
      .get()    
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc, i) => {
            // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            console.log(doc.data().email_id)
            for (let i = 0; i < doc.data().length; i++) {
              email_user[i] = doc.data().email_id[i];
              console.log("email_user : ", email_user[i])
            }
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
        return emailcatch.map((doc) => doc.data().email_id);

    } catch{
      console.log("Error")
    }
   
      



       <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={items}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={setValue}
        setItems={setItems}
      />
```

[image]

the log for the fetch function works fine and shows emails perfectly in the below way

```
 LOG  ABC@111.com
 LOG  XYZ@1111.com
 LOG  SDS@1111.com
 LOG  ASD@11111.com
 LOG  gasd@123.com
 LOG  asdf@ll.com
```

Comment: Where does `DropDownPicker` come from and what do its props do?

Comment: import DropDownPicker from "react-native-dropdown-picker";

this is how i imported it

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to load the list of email addresses into `items` within an effect hook.

For example, create a function to retrieve the `email_id` properties as an array then call it in your component's *on-mount* effect hook and map the results to the [Item Schema](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/item-schema) required by the dropdown component before setting them into `setItems`.

You can also take advantage of the [*loading*](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/loading) feature of the dropdown.

For example

```js
// This could be defined in its own, easily testable module
const getUserEmails = async () => {
  const { docs } = await dob
    .collection("users")
    .where("email_id", "!=", "")
    .get();

  return docs.map((doc) => doc.data().email_id);
};

// Here's your component
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    getUserEmails()
      .then((emails) => {
        // Map the email array to the Item Schema
        setItems(emails.map((email) => ({ label: email, value: email })));
      })
      .catch(console.error)
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      loading={isLoading}
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
    />
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: could you help ?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'getUserEmails().then')

this is the error shown to me

Comment: @The.Kingslayer Have you defined `getUserEmails` exactly like in my answer? Where did you define it? If you're still having issues, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73862621/edit) to show the code you're using

Comment: check the code.

Comment: @The.Kingslayer sorry, what is `emailcatch`? That doesn't appear anywhere in my answer

Comment: @The.Kingslayer I've edited my answer to make it as clear as possible

Comment: done bro, i tried by push property

Comment: @The.Kingslayer sorry, I have no idea what that means